# How to peek System.Linq source codes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I had the source code of system.linq from https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

I want to watch my queries step by step with breakpoints
to understand better. how can i integrate these codes into my own project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, open the Tools menu, click Options…, and go to Debugging. Uncheck "Enable Just My Code" and check "Enable .NET Framework source stepping". This would allow you to step into .NET Framework code as if it were your own.

[image: VS Options]

Comment: Actually my problem is  that My solution and source codes are in the different folders and i cant run both.

Comment: I could not fully explain because my English is bad

Comment: @EnesSez do you want to build .Net code locally??? There should be readme on Github how to do that... but why would one need to do that to step through automatically downloaded code I'm not sure. You probably want to carefully think what you actually want to do and ask separate question.